# Wordpress Permlinks 404 Not Found

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the latest WordPress on my EC2 Ubuntu 13.1 server.
Once I have changed the permlinks to use /%post-name%/, I encounter 404 not found for posts.
I have followed almost everything here, but still having the issue.
http://www.felfelworld.com/2013/02/12/page-not-found-permalink-wordpress/

FYI, I remember I did disable the directory listing for my apache server using SELinux (if I remember it correctly)

Comment: This question does not appear to be appropriate for StackOverflow (see "[What topics can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"). You might want to try asking it over on the WordPress StackExchange site: "[WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)".

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled on the server?

Comment: Thanks McNab, that solves the trick!  I need to turn RewriteEngine On in apache2.conf

Answer (score 1):

in order to have the Permalinks working you need:

- Apache web server with the mod_rewrite module installed
- The FollowSymLinks option enabled
- FileInfo directives allowed
- An .htaccess file

You can read more on the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).